# Insert into select statment ID not been copied

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with same structure when copying from table A to table B I want table A ID and `image_name`  to be copied into table B where table A and B has id which is primary key and auto incremented. But ID has new value in table B.

table structure:

```
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `camera_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `nread` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `millisecs` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` mediumblob,
  `checked` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

$sql = "INSERT INTO $newCamTable (plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image) SELECT plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image FROM $camTable WHERE id=\"$tableEntryId\"";
    logit($sql);
```

Comment: I can't see eny questions?!

Comment: ID is not been copied it has new ID value on table B...not an error  exactly

Comment: Note that a variable table name is often symptomatic of poor design. That aside, for further help provide the echo of the query, and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $newCamTable (plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image) SELECT plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image FROM $camTable WHERE id=\"$tableEntryId\"";
```

and add the id field:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $newCamTable (id, plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image) SELECT id,plate, nread, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name, image FROM $camTable WHERE id=\"$tableEntryId\"";
```

This will prevent the autoincrement functionality from generating a new ID in table 'B'.

**BUT**

you manually need to manage that IDs are unique in table 'B'